# Decoding a base64 string from windows phone

Tags: c#, utf8-decode

i am getting a Soap response which contains a base64 string. I am using XDocument to get the value of the element and a function like this to read it

```
 public void main()
    {
  //****UPDATE
  string data64 = "";
  data64 = removeNewLinesFromString(data64);
  content = data64.ToCharArray();

  byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(content, 0, content.Length);
  Stream stream  = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
  BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream,Encoding.UTF8);                                        
  string object64 = SoapSerializable.ReadUTF(reader);
  }
```

this is the readUTF function

```
   public static String ReadUTF(BinaryReader reader)
        {
            // read the following string's length in bytes
            int length = Helpers.FlipInt32(reader.ReadInt32());

            // read the string's data bytes
            byte[] utfString = reader.ReadBytes(length);

            // get the string by interpreting the read data as UTF-8
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utfString, 0, utfString.Length);
        }
```

and my FlipInt32 function

```
public static Int32 FlipInt32(Int32 value)
        {
            Int32 a = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
            Int32 b = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
            Int32 c = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
            Int32 d = (value >> 0) & 0xFF;
            return (((((d << 8) | c) << 8) | b) << 8) | a;
        }
```

but the resulting values are slightly different from the results an online decoder gives.

I am missing something here?

Comment: Where is your base64 string? How do you decode it? How do you use XDocument? what is the use of BinaryReader ?

Comment: How relates base64 encoding with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: L.B i updated my question. Hamlet Hakobyan could you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Why that effort? Can't you just use Convert.FromBase64String() if you already have the base64 string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with `BinaryReader` But here is what I do to get
`this is a dummy encoded base64 string` from your base64 data

```
string data64 = "dGhpcyBpcyBhIGR1bW15IGVuY29kZWQgYmFzZTY0IHN0cmluZy4=";
var buf = Convert.FromBase64String(data64);
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this seems to works if the data64 is simple as that dummy one, but if i try to put something more complex it returns a few different characters and some are displayed like that �.. why is this happening.

Comment: @Billatron How can I answer without knowing your original base64 string?

Comment: @Billatron your new base64 string doesn't contain a *string*, but some binary data. Without any context, I can't say what it means. It can be *anything*

Comment: that might sound completely noobish but i am not familiar with what would a context be for this specific thing. where should i find it ?

Comment: @Billatron You posted a binary data encoded in a base64 string and i don't know what to do with it? How did you generate it? what is in it? BTW: I am not interested in decrypting it anyway.

Comment: i am getting it as a response of a login request to a web service. where should i find the context of the soap response??